# Keyboard calculator system (Keyboard with embedded calculator)

Tags: keyboard, performance, calculator

Many users want to make numerical calculations and use the final result in their applications. And in the current situation users keep a calculator at their desktop to perform calculation (note that I don't mean Calculator Application when saying calculator, but i mean electronic device, and when I say desktop I mean a table where users work). They input the result using the computer keyboard on a their applications then. But it would be perfect to have a calculator implemented right in the keyboard and not use additional device. This would rise the speed of work, I think. And I think the only thing to add to the keyboard is just a small 8 or 12 digit screen to show numbers that users enter. And would be much effective to give opportunity to send the final result right to the application. 
After several searches in Internet I have found [this](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/6114977.pdf) patent on such a keyboard. But up to now I haven't met this kind of keyboard.
Has anybody met this kind of keyboard somewhere? Or have you used it? What do you think, does it help to optimize the problem I mentioned in the beginning of the question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really the same as you describe, but my current keyboard has a "Calculator" button in the top-right directly above the number pad that launches calc directly - and has you hand in the right place to start punching in numbers.

To my mind the two major advantages of using software to run numbers is that you can copy/paste the answer (which having an external calc built in to a keyboard can easily solve, I'm sure what with it being an input device) and *ability*.

For example, a number-pad calculator would be limited to basic arithmetic, yes? But, the standard Win7 calculator has modes for Scientific / Programmer / Statistics, which are each reasonably useful (the binary / hex readouts in Programmer mode I find particularly handy).

Personally, I'm not sure an external calc built in to a keyboard would really help. But that said, I sometimes fire up Excel to crunch numbers if I feel the need, and I don't think I've used a stand alone calculator in years...

Comment: yeah, you´re right but imagine you don´t want to switch between calculator app and the app you´re working in, but you want to calculate something and put result right in your app.

Comment: @Bakhiyor Quite true, you could just ctrl+c, alt+F4, ctrl+v. But this isn't going to be useful if you need to input multiple calculations, or the different parts of a longer calculation. I guess the middle solution is that - if the calculations are important to use of the software - calculator functionality should be provided by the app directly, this way it is tailored to the relevant input and ability requirements. But obviously, this is not something you can do most of the time, unless you're personally involved with designing/building the app in question.

Answer (score 2):

Start -> Run -> calc.exe.

Comment: but it's not convenient is it?

Comment: Yes, it is. And it's way more convenient than anything you'll find in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I remember seeing them way back in the days when I was running a 10mhz 8088 based PC XT.  I never bought one since it didn't solve a problem I had, but I did play with one in a little private computer store once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a current product I came across when I was looking at Bluetooth keypads: [Interlink VP6270 Bluetooth Calculator Keypad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A57WZU). (Note that it being a Bluetooth keypad means that it has the shape of a traditional calculator and can be used independently without unplugging a cable.)

I have no idea if it is actually a good product; this is just an example of the sort of thing you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking this feature, I've developed an Android keyboard app with a built-in calculator. Input and output are linked directly to the input device. Simply press the '≛' button to read input from the current cursor position and automatically type the answer. For example, entering 1+2+3≛ will replace '≛' to [=6] like below:
1+2+3[=6]
Additionally, the app offers function definition capabilities, including recursive function.
Fibonacci sequence can be programmed and calculated as shown below;
clear()[✓]
f(1)=1[✓]
f(2)=1[✓]
f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)[✓]
f(100)[=3.54224848179262E20]
f(10)[=55.0]

Below is the app link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taconicanalytic.mathkeyboard&hl=en_AU&gl=US

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: a question  on keyboard (app) with calculator capability.